# making 'some_element'.present? in watir wait for less than 5 secs

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

How do we make some_element.present? or some_element.visible? wait for less than 5 secs.? Because I think some_element.present? alone will wait for default value of 30 secs before timing out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to shorten the length of time before timeout, by default its set to 30 seconds, see below on how to customize that time.

According to http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Explicit waits

There are four built in methods that you can use to make your waiting experience more pleasant (and remove those evil sleep statements from your code)

```
Watir::Wait.until { ... }: where you can wait for a block to be true
object.when_present.set: where you can do something when it’s present
object.wait_until_present:; where you just wait until something is present
object.wait_while_present:; where you just wait until something disappears
The default timeout for all these methods is 30 seconds, but your can pass an argument to any of these to increase (or decrease) it as needed.
```

and http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/EventuallyPresent

```
- (Object) wait_until_present(timeout = nil)
```

Waits until the element is present.

Examples:

```
browser.button(:id => 'foo').wait_until_present
Parameters:
timeout (Fixnum) (defaults to: nil) — seconds to wait before timing out

- (Object) wait_while_present(timeout = nil)
```

Waits while the element is present.

Examples:

```
browser.button(:id => 'foo').wait_while_present
Parameters:
timeout (Integer) (defaults to: nil) — seconds to wait before timing out

- (Object) when_present(timeout = nil)
```

Waits until the element is present.

Examples:

```
browser.button(:id => 'foo').when_present.click
browser.div(:id => 'bar').when_present { |div| ... }
browser.p(:id => 'baz').when_present(60).text
Parameters:
timeout (Fixnum) (defaults to: nil) — seconds to wait before timing out
```

Comment: Thanks Carldmitch..Appreciate a lot. wait_until_present(x) solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks. So how do i do something like, if the element is present, click it and if not present move to next step in test. To me it looks like using something like:  If button.present? do this.... end. Move to next line. But what should i do in case if that element is ajax element and needs to wait for couple of seconds. If present?  doesn't wait then that if statement will fail right there because the element has not loaded in the page yet.

Answer (score 3):

The `Element#present?` (and `Element#visible?` and `Element#exists?`) method does not wait at all. You can see this by checking the time before and after attempting to locate an element that is not present:

```
puts Time.now
#=> 2014-07-31 22:14:08 -0400
puts browser.element(id: 'does_not_exist').present?
#=> false
puts Time.now
#=> 2014-07-31 22:14:08 -0400
```

As you can see, the time before and after checking the prescence of the element is a negligible amount.

It should be noted that the above was executed against a tiny page. For a very large page, which would require more inspection, the method could take longer to execute. However, that would be an issue of execution time rather than being Watir is actually waiting.

Comment: So I am thinking its not good to use.present? for the ajax element right? . Generally I use present? to check if the element is present before clicking on it. SO, how should i write my code to check for the presence of element in the page and time out after 4 secs. if not present.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of .present? I beleive using .present? along with wait_until_present(x) solves the ajax issue too.