# Wait when text become present

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I want to wait when required text will become present.
I use:

```
@browser.text('required text').when_present
```

And I get an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

How it can be implemented? I wan't to wait only for text without any dependency to html element.

Comment: Probably [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25072034/6475535) you can find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using page-object gem without any dependency to html element:

```ruby
@page.wait_until { @page.text.include? 'required text' }
```

[Reference](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/PageObject#wait_until-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great variant.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is `@browser.text.include?('required text')`
This should help you get rid of the error.

Comment: Note that this will only check whether the text is currently included. This will not address "waiting" for the text to be included.

Answer (score 0):

better yet you can do it like this:

```
Watir::Wait.until(10) { @browser.text.include?('required text') }
```

the default value of timeout is 60 seconds if not set, its set to 10 seconds in the example above.

[Reference](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir%2FWait%3Auntil)

Comment: This will result in a `NoMethorError` exception since `wait_until_present` is not defined for `FalseClass` or `TrueClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for text for the whole page, it may be more efficient to create an element for the text.

span(:ur_name, :text=>/partial string/)

or however you prefer defining it and then call the [element level wait functions](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Ajax-Calls) for the object. Ofcourse, you can also dynamically declare the element if the text is dynamic.

span(:ur_name, :text => "#{variable_containing_text}")

page.ur_name_element.when_present

A trivial benefit being this ensures your text is not displayed out of place, esp if dups are possible. If the element doesnt support text locator, you can still identify the element, check for text and then use the element wait.

Answer (score 0):

### `wait_until`

As per [the latest docs](http://watir.com/guides/waiting/), use `.wait_until( &:present? )`:

```rb
@browser.text( "required text" ).wait_until( &:present? )
```